# Get data from nested array of objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, bash, dictionary

I am trying to parson the JSON file to get specific values and .items[] name from dictionary in the same file.

Source.json File: https://jqplay.org/s/0-o4HOox-K

```js
{
  "name": "ABC Company",
  "assetbase": [{
    "name": "Added assets from API",
    "type": "access-section",
    "assetbase": [{
      "name": "Database A",
      "asset-number": 1,
      "items": ["0ABC-001", "0ABC-003", "0ABC-004"]
    }, {
      "name": "Database B",
      "asset-number": 2,
      "items": ["0ABC-001"]
    }, {
      "name": "Database C",
      "asset-number": 3,
      "items": ["0ABC-002", "0ABC-003"]
    }]
  }],
  "objects-dictionary": [{
    "uid": "0ABC-001",
    "name": "Cluster A"
  }, {
    "uid": "0ABC-002",
    "name": "Cluster B"

  }, {
    "uid": "0ABC-003",
    "name": "Unit-001"
  }, {
    "uid": "0ABC-004",
    "name": "Unit-002"
  }]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
"Database A","Cluster A";"Unit-001";"Unit-002"
"Database B","Cluster A"
"Database C","Cluster B";"Unit-001"
```

I have look around similar threads and randomly tested on jqplay but simply cannot get the output.

Comment: Firstly, please add the code you've written to solve this to the question so we can help you debug it. Secondly, the expected output is not a valid data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Pure `jq` solution:

```
jq -r '([(."objects-dictionary"[] | {key:.uid, value:.name})] | from_entries
       ) as $obj
       | .assetbase[] | .assetbase[]
       | [.name, (.items[] as $i | $obj[$i])]
       | @csv' < file.json
```

It uses only commas, no semicolons, but I fear jq can't do that.

Comment: Concise and nice solution, thank you sir for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using **jq** ([link](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)), you can easily parse .json files.

Here's a pretty close solution for you:

```
$ jq -r '.assetbase[].assetbase[] | .name' test.json |
    while read name; do echo -ne "\"$name\"," ;
      jq -r --arg name "$name" '.assetbase[].assetbase[] |
      select (.name | contains($name)) | .items[]' test.json |
      while read uid; do
        jq -r --arg uid $uid '."objects-dictionary"[] |
        select (.uid | contains($uid)) | .name' test.json |
        while read oname; do echo -ne "\"$oname\";" ; done;
      done; echo -ne "\n" ;
    done

"Database A","Cluster A";"Unit-001";"Unit-002";
"Database B","Cluster A";
"Database C","Cluster B";"Unit-001";
```

You can easily install it via your common package manager:
`sudo yum install -y jq` for RPM-based distros (like RedHat), or `sudo apt-get install -y jq` for Debian-based (Ubuntu, etc.);

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bash solution, but a JS one.

The snippet below creates an object that has the database names as keys (look in the console):

```js
const data = {
  "name": "ABC Company",
  "assetbase": [{
    "name": "Added assets from API",
    "type": "access-section",
    "assetbase": [{
      "name": "Database A",
      "asset-number": 1,
      "items": ["0ABC-001", "0ABC-003", "0ABC-004"]
    }, {
      "name": "Database B",
      "asset-number": 2,
      "items": ["0ABC-001"]
    }, {
      "name": "Database C",
      "asset-number": 3,
      "items": ["0ABC-002", "0ABC-003"]
    }]
  }],
  "objects-dictionary": [{
    "uid": "0ABC-001",
    "name": "Cluster A"
  }, {
    "uid": "0ABC-002",
    "name": "Cluster B"

  }, {
    "uid": "0ABC-003",
    "name": "Unit-001"
  }, {
    "uid": "0ABC-004",
    "name": "Unit-002"
  }]
}

const mapAssets = (assetbase, dictionary) => {
  const ret = assetbase.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (typeof a[c.name] === "undefined") a[c.name] = []
    a[c.name].push(c.name)
    c.items.forEach(e => {
      const {
        name
      } = dictionary.find(el => {
        return el.uid === e
      })
      a[c.name].push(name)
    })
    return a
  }, {})
  return ret
}

const mapped = mapAssets(data.assetbase[0].assetbase, data["objects-dictionary"])

console.log('mapped:', mapped)
```